# HttpClient HttpResponseMessage Address / URI

Tags: c#, httpclient, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I am developing a C# WinRT application that makes POST and GET requests to a webserver.

Does anyone know if there is a way to get the Response URI / Address when using a HttpClient object?.

If I use the HttpWebRequest / HttpWebResponse classes, then I can get this information (via the ResponseUri property in HttpWebResponse), but I don't see how to obtain it using the HttpClient / HttpResponseMessage classes.

Thanks

Comment: Just to make this even more explicit - `HttpClient` is available starting with .NET 4.5. Took me a while to find out why I cannot find assembly System.Net.Http (in which the type is defined) with my 4.0 framework :)

Comment: I think you can get the redirected UI from HttpResponseMessage.RequestMessage.RequestUri

Answer (score 23):

This is two years old, but I just came across this question with the exact same desire, and it was answered in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677112/httpclient-httpresponsemessage-address-uri#comment15482091_11677112) by [@PeterRitchie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5620/peter-ritchie), so I am copying that for future visitors.

> I think you can get the redirected UI from HttpResponseMessage.RequestMessage.RequestUri

Comment: HttpResponseMessage.RequestMessage refers to the request which led to the response message. 

HttpResponseMessage.RequestMessage.RequestUri refers to the uri that was requested not the last uri from which the response was redirected to.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.aspx

Comment: @stormwild This works, though... I agree that it's not the most discoverable design. But the `HttpResponseMessage.RequestMessage` reflects the request made most recently. In most cases, that's the request you file. But in cases described here, it is the request filed after the 302 (or what have you).

Comment: This property is the request message that led to this response message. For a request sent using HttpClient, this property will point to the actual request message leading to the final response. Note that this may not be the same message the user provided when sending the request. This is typically the case if the request needs to be resent due to redirects or authentication. This property can be used to determine what URI actually created the response (useful in case of redirects).